# How to import images bucket from AWS S3 using python

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to import images bucket from AWS s3 using python without declaring LOCAL_PATH, i want total bucket images in python environment in array format, from one week on words i am facing this issue, please any one can help out of this.

Here is my python code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os         
from random import shuffle 
from tqdm import tqdm      
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
import boto
import boto.s3.connection
import sys
import traceback    
conn =   boto.connect_s3('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('dp-xray')

LOCAL_PATH='E:/'

for l in bucket_train:
    keyString = str(l.key)
    d = LOCAL_PATH + keyString
    try:
        l.get_contents_to_filename(d)
    except OSError:
        if not os.path.exists(d):
            os.mkdir(d)

def create_label(image_name):
    """ Create an one-hot encoded vector from image name """
    word_label = image_name.split('.')[-3]
    if word_label == 'Nor':
        return np.array([1,0])
elif word_label == 'Nod':
        return np.array([0,1])

def create_train_data():
training_data = []
for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
    path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR, img)
    img_data = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img_data = cv2.resize(img_data, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    training_data.append([np.array(img_data), create_label(img)])
shuffle(training_data)
np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)
return training_data

train_data = create_train_data()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well not sure what is the exact error you are facing. Please post the log. 
I am sure you would have solved this by now. just to help others.

we should do something like this:

```
bucket = conn.Bucket(''dp-xray'')
objs = bucket.objects.all()
```

objs is whats you are expecting an array of object summary.

if you want image prefix then do

```
response = conn.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
```

key you will get in each object summary.

(not tested code but should work)